# Reading the results from an infinite loop using threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, thread-safety

I am currently working with python v.2.7 on windows 8.

My programme is using threads. The threads execute a method named as `getData()` for infinite time that does the following:

- makes the current thread to sleep for some time
- calls the `compareValues()`
- retrieve the information from the `compareValues`() and adds them to a
  list called `myList`

The `compareValues()` does the following:

- generates a random number
- checks if it is less than 5 or if it is greater than or equal to 5
  and yields the result along with the current thread's name

I save the results of these threads to a list named as `myList` and then finally print this `myList`.

**Problem**: As the `getData()` is looping for infinite time. How can I access the `myList` for retrieving the results? What would be a good approach in this case. *If you remove the `while True:` then the programm works fine.*

**Code**:

```
import time
from random import randrange
import threading

myList = []
def getData(i):
   while True:
        print "Sleep for %d"%i
        time.sleep(i)
        data = compareValues()
        for d in list(data):
            myList.append(d)

def compareValues():
        number = randrange(10)
        name = threading.current_thread().name
        if number >= 5:
             yield "%s: Greater than or equal to 5: %d  "%(name, number)
        else:
             yield "%s: Less than 5: %d  "%(name, number)

threadList = []
wait = randrange(10)+1
t = threading.Thread(name = 'First-Thread', target = getData, args=(wait,))
threadList.append(t)
t.start()
wait = randrange(3)+1
t = threading.Thread(name = 'Second-Thread', target = getData, args=(wait,))
threadList.append(t)
t.start()
for t in threadList:
    t.join()
print "The final list"
print myList
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you want the `getData()` method to loop infinitely?

Comment: This is an example of my real world problem. In my real world problem I have to read some different values from a server and update my old values respectively after every 5 seconds or so. So, I want to read values from the server infinitely. I just tried to convert my real world problem to this dummy problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of inconsistencies that may help to make the code look a little bit more clear. For instance:

1. `compareValues()` should **return 'The result in string Format......'** and not yield. Am I right? Because this function is going to evaluate only one value at a time.
2. `getData()` should look like:

   ```
   def getData(i):
       while True:
           print "Sleep for %d"%i
           time.sleep(i)
           myList.append(compareValues())
   ```

Exactly for the same reason as I said in the previous point.

P.S.: I don't know why the code is not formatting properly. Sorry...  :-(

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, your suggestions provided some hints that assisted me to solve my problem by modifying my code.

Comment: Wonderful! I'm happy about that.